# Python - Parameters

Tags: python

I have a code like this:

```
>>> def enterText(value):
    command = input ("enter text: ")
    value = command

>>> def start():
    text = ""
    enterText(text)
    print ("you entered: "+str(text))
```

I have tied a lot of things but I can't seem to figure it out. I'm new to Python, can help me pass a string through functions? Thanks!

Comment: Did you want to `return` the command?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings in Python are *immutable*. You need to return the string from `enterText()` so you can use it within `start()`.

```
>>> def enterText():
    return input("enter text: ")

>>> def start():
    text = enterText()
    print ("you entered: " + str(text))
```

A given string object *cannot* be changed. When you call `enterText(text)`, `value` will refer to the empty string object created within `start()`.

Assigning to `value` then *rebinds* the variable, i.e. it connects the *name* "value" with the object referenced by the right-hand side of the assignment. An assignment to a plain variable does *not* modify an object.

The `text` variable, however, will continue to refer to the empty string until you assign to `text` again. But since you don't do that, it can't work.

Comment: You would get the same rebinding behavior even if `value` was a mutable list. I think you should probably add something about local vs. global scopes to make this a complete answer. Nonetheless, +1.

Comment: @JoelCornett Which part would you rephrase? I didn't mean to make it sound like the rebinding only happens because strings are immutable.

Comment: It's not a huge deal. Your first sentence seems to imply that the immutability of strings is the reason why the assignment operation isn't working. The rest of your answer clarifies the point though.

Comment: @JoelCornett Ah yes, I can see what you mean. Maybe I'll come to think of a better wording.